# Mapbox GL latest 0.26.0 Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

Has anyone run across the following error in the latest mapbox gl? This happens when setFilter of the map.

```
VM5448:227 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined(…)
t.setFilter @ mapbox-gl.js?6b34:formatted:6061
e.setFilter @ mapbox-gl.js?6b34:formatted:10080
(anonymous function) @ map.service.ts?33cd:135SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ VM5448:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ VM5448:172
Subscriber._next @ VM5448:125
Subscriber.next @ VM5448:89
handler @ VM5521:126
Evented.fire @ mapbox-gl.js?6b34:formatted:11031
h @ mapbox-gl.js?6b34:formatted:8249
u @ mapbox-gl.js?6b34:formatted:8213
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js?fad3:265
onInvokeTask @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6197ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js?fad3:264
Zone.runTask @ zone.js?fad3:154ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js?fad3:335
```

t.setFilter @ mapbox-gl.js?6b34:formatted:6061

```
            t.prototype.setFilter = function(e, t) {
                this._checkLoaded();
                var r = this.getLayer(e);
                return null !== t && this._validate(validateStyle.filter, "layers." + r.id + ".filter", t) ? this : util.deepEqual(r.filter, t) ? this : (r.filter = util.clone(t),
                this._updateLayer(r))
            }
```

Comment: Can you post the code that is throwing the error please? i.e. what you're calling `map.setFilter()` with.

Comment: My code is similar to the:
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/hover-styles/


Code snippet:
`Observable.fromEvent(this._map, "mousemove").subscribe(
       function(x: MapMouseEvent) {
        let features = this._map.queryRenderedFeatures(x.point, { layers: [this._layerId] });
        if (features.length) {
         this._map.setFilter(this._layerId, ["all", ["==", "aaa", features[0].properties.aaa], ["==", "bbb", "B"]]);
        } else {
         this._map.setFilter(this._layerId, ["all", ["==", "aaa", ""], ["==", "bbb", "B"]]);
        }
       }.bind(this));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is closed. Upgrade to 0.28.0